# How to get json response in classic asp post request with https url

Tags: json, asp-classic

```
set urlname = "https://URL/sso/json/sessions/?_action=validate"

set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", urlname, false  
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "ms-sso", encryptedTicket
xmlhttp.send
set status = xmlhttp.responseText


response.Write("<script language=javascript>console.log(' statuss : " & status & "'); </script>")
```

I have above code block:

I am trying to call https URL using POST request
Its just basically decrypt the token (ms-sso) and gives GUID in response.
but I am getting a black response in status code and responseText.

but it works fine if I checked with Fiddler :

```
POST:"https://URL/sso/json/sessions/?_action=validate"
Content-Type: application/json
ms-sso: AQIC5wM2LY4SfcyB2ttvMve81T42_U1gUOWFv4grmOSRssg.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABM0MTQxMTQ5MjM5MzE3OTA5MTA3AAJTMQACMTI.*

{"valid":true,"uid":"8FC1D617-8E32-45E2-9417-0323491765D2","realm":"/msusers"}
```

Why this is happening ? any idea?

Comment: You don't need `set` for strings. `urlname = "......"` and `status = "...."`. Do you have `On Error Resume Next` in your code somewhere? if so, comment it out

Comment: yes, we have 'on error resume next' but it's within the functions and my code is outside that block. Does it matter?